# MKMapViw Direction Instructions

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I created a route between the current user location and some point on the map. I can get instructions on the direction from MKRoute. The question is:
How can I detect when in the next crossroad need to turn left or right? It should look like this: "At the next crossroad turn left".
I'll be happy to see the solution in Swift or in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with following code

```
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
            [myMapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads]; // Draws the route above roads, but below labels.
            // You can also get turn-by-turn steps, distance, advisory notices, ETA, etc by accessing various route properties.
        }
    }
}];
```

Go through different `MKRoute` properties to get what you want.

Comment: I already got this. I need to know when the user is almost at the corner. I am trying to check regionDidExit method, but there is no information about the streets.

Answer (score 0):

the project and you will see your custom annotations, showing your source and destination coordinates on mapView.

Its time to the direction between the two annotation.

Follow this link:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute

An **MKRoute** object defines the geometry for the route—that is, it contains line segments associated with specific map coordinates. A route object may also include other information, such as the name of the route, its distance, and the expected travel time. For example, a step might involve following a single road until a turn is required.

Add the following code in your viewController.m class.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:sourceCoordinate.coordinate addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];
   MKMapItem *sourceMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:source];
   MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:destinationCoordinate.coordinate addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];
   MKMapItem *distMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:destination];
   MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
   [request setSource:sourceMapItem];
   [request setDestination:distMapItem];
   [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];
   MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];
   [direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   if (!error) {
       for (MKRoute *route in [response routes]) {
            [_mMapView addOverlay:[route polyline] level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
       }
   }
 }];
}
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        [renderer setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [renderer setLineWidth:3.0];
         return renderer;
     }
   return nil;
}
```

For Swift

**Update**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:"", longitude: ""), addressDictionary: nil))
    request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: "", longitude: ""), addressDictionary: nil))
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    request.transportType = .automobile

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
        guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

        for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
            self.mapView.add(route.polyline)
            self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlay as! MKPolyline)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    return renderer
}
```